# Error de incompatible types Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa donde el usuario dara su numero y contable y su nombre, sin embargo no corre y aparece un error diciendo  error: incompatible types  required: int
  found:    String

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal en mi codigo?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Capturas{
   public static void main(String[]args){



      String[]nombre=new String[5];
      String auxnombre;
      int[]num=new int[5];
      int opcionmenu=0;
      int capture1;
      int ejecutar=0;
      int auxnum=0;
      int casillas=0;
      int x=0;
      int error;
      int otro=0;
      int yaesta=0;
      int renglon;


          do
          {

         opcionmenu=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa la opcion deseada: \n 1.Captura \n 2.Consulta \n 3.Cambios \n 4.Cancelaciones \n 5.Reinstalacion \n 6.Salida");
         if(opcionmenu==1)
         {
            if(casillas<4)
            {
               yaesta=0;
               auxnum=Integer.parseInt(auxnum=JoptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el numero contable"));

               for(x=1; x<=4; x++)
               {
                  if(auxnum==num[x])
                  {
                     yaesta=1;
                  }
               }
               if(yaesta==1)
               {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El numero ya esta registrado");
               }
               if(yaesta==0)
               {
                  renglon=0;

                  for(x=1; x<=4; x++)
                  {
                     if(nombre[x]!=null)
                     {
                        renglon=renglon+1;
                     }
                  }
                  renglon=renglon+1;
                  num[renglon]=auxnum;
                  nombre[renglon]=auxnum;
                  nombre[renglon]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el Nombre");
                  casillas=casillas+1;
               }
            }
         }
      }
      while(opcion!=6);

   }
}
```

Comment: Tu código tiene mas de un error. Deberías incluir cada error, o especificar cual error te interesa. Además, cuando recibes errores de compilación, usualmente también el mensaje te indica cual sentencia está en error. Es importante incluir esta información también.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que siempre cuando tienes un error compartes el (StackTrace) completo. Hace mucho mas fácil de encontrar los errores y mas encima te podemos explicar como lo identificas tu mismo. No importa si es largo, es lo que se necesita.

Comment: Estos son los errores que  salen

Capturas.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
               auxnum=Integer.parseInt(JoptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el numero contable"));
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable JoptionPane
  location: class Capturas
Capturas.java:56: error: incompatible types
                  nombre[renglon]=auxnum;
                                  ^
  required: String
  found:    int
Capturas.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
      while(opcion!=6);
            ^
  symbol:   variable opcion
  location: class Capturas
3 errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uno se tus errores está aquí :

```
auxnum=Integer.parseInt(auxnum=JoptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el numero contable"));
```

Debería ser sólo así

```
    auxnum=Integer.parseInt(JoptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el numero contable"));
```

El otro error es aquí:

```
opcionmenu=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa la opcion deseada: \n 1.Captura \n 2.Consulta \n 3.Cambios \n 4.Cancelaciones \n 5.Reinstalacion \n 6.Salida");
```

Debería ser así:

```
opcionmenu=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa la opcion deseada: \n 1.Captura \n 2.Consulta \n 3.Cambios \n 4.Cancelaciones \n 5.Reinstalacion \n 6.Salida") );
```

Esos son los errores que he identificado que tendrían que ver con el error que indicas que tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

El error en tu código se encuentra en esta línea:

```
opcionmenu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
```

Básicamente se produce porque `opcionmenu` es una variable de tipo `int`, que espera que almacenes un número entero dentro de ella, sin embargo la función `showInputDialog(...)` del objeto `JOptionPane` devuelve una cadena de texto o `string` en vez de un `int`, es decir, lo que sea que hayas escrito en el input de la ventana emergente, sin importar si lo que escribiste ha sido un número.

Para solucionarlo solo debes intentar parsear el `string` a `int`:

```
string input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
int opcionmenu = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Este código funcionará siempre y cuando lo que hayas escrito sea un número entero. Pero fallará de lo contrario. Para evitarlo, solo debes manejar la excepción que se produce en este caso y evitar que la aplicación se rompa:

```
string input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);

try {
  int opcionmenu = Integer.parseInt(input);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
  // Indicar al usuario que debe ingresar un número entero...
}
```